# Remove namespace from type_id_with_cv<>()::pretty_name()

Tags: c++, boost, typeid

I'm using the following code to retrieve the name of a class:

```
template <typename T>
string GetName(const T& object) {

    using type = typename remove_const<typename remove_reference<decltype(object)>::type>::type;
    return boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<type>().pretty_name();

}
```

The code works well. However the returned string contains also the namespaces. Is there a boost function that returns only the class name?
I know I could write it myself, the point is just not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Some wheels are designed to be reinvented.

Comment: @Maverik Regex it.

Answer (score 0):

This is another invention of the wheel and horrible but quick solution, basically, exploit the similarity between namespace structure and directory structure.

```
#include<boost/type_index.hpp>
#include<boost/filesystem/path.hpp>

namespace A{
    namespace B{
        struct C{};
    }
}


int main(){   
    std::string s = boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<A::B::C const*&>().pretty_name();
    replace(begin(s), end(s), ':', '/');
    replace(begin(s), end(s), ' ', '.');

    using namespace boost::filesystem;
    assert( path(s).string() == "A//B//C.const*&" );
    assert( path(s).filename() == "C.const*&" );
    assert( path(s).extension() == ".const*&" );
    assert( path(s).stem() == "C" );
    assert( path(s).parent_path() == "A//B");
    assert( path(s).parent_path().parent_path() == "A");
}
```

or package it into a simple ugly class:

```
#include<boost/type_index.hpp>
#include<boost/filesystem/path.hpp>

namespace A{
    namespace B{
        struct C{};
    }
}

template<class T>
class typename_info_t{
    boost::filesystem::path p_;
public:
    typename_info_t(){
        std::string s = boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name();
        replace(begin(s), end(s), ':', '/');
        replace(begin(s), end(s), ' ', '.');
        p_ = s;
    }
    std::string full_name() const{
        std::string s = p_.string();
        replace(begin(s), end(s), '/', ':');
        replace(begin(s), end(s), '.', ' ');
        return s;
    }
    std::string namespace_name() const{
        std::string s = p_.parent_path().string();
        replace(begin(s), end(s), '/', ':');
        return s;
    }
    std::string class_name() const{
        std::string s = p_.stem().string();
        replace(begin(s), end(s), '/', ':');
        return s;
    }
    std::string class_name_with_cvr() const{
        std::string s = p_.filename().string();
        replace(begin(s), end(s), '/', ':');
        replace(begin(s), end(s), '.', ' ');
        return s;
    }
    std::string cvr() const{ // begins with space
        std::string s = p_.extension().string();
        replace(begin(s), end(s), '.', ' ');
        return s;
    }
};

template<class TT> typename_info_t<TT> typename_info(){return {};}


int main(){
    assert( typename_info<A::B::C const*&>().full_name() == "A::B::C const*&" );
    assert( typename_info<A::B::C const*&>().namespace_name() == "A::B" );
    assert( typename_info<A::B::C const*&>().class_name() == "C" );
    assert( typename_info<A::B::C const*&>().class_name_with_cvr() == "C const*&" );
    assert( typename_info<A::B::C const*&>().cvr() == " const*&");

}
```

(limitation: '*' pointer qualifier is not part of the class name here, unfortunatelly this forces to use `#include<boost/filesystem.hpp>` or `#include<experimental/filesystem>` which are non header-only libraries.